# What is an ADM Template?

Tags: group-policy

In the context of Windows Group Policy, what is an ADM Template?

Answer (score 3):

They outline registry changes through group policy in a more readable format, in extremely basic terms. Much more information at wikipedia -> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Administrative_Template

Also a how-to for creating your own; http://www.datacrash.net/howtos/howto/create-your-own-adm-templates.html

Answer (score 2):

An Administrative Template basically adds new options to Group Policy.

For example, we add an ADM Template to allow control over Outlook Settings through Group Policy Editor.